# Using a basement I-beam to ground house

Tags: grounding

I recently replaced the old galvanized plumbing in my 1946 house with PEX. I need to run an earth from the breaker box to the copper water supply pipe. The panel and water supply pipe are at opposite corners of the house. I would need 75 feet of wire to connect the two points. There is a steel I-beam running the length of the house in the basement. Can I use this I-Beam to make the connection between the two points?  The beam has several steel supports going into the basement floor so it is somewhat earthed as well. I would not rely on those as reliable earth.

Comment: Why not just go though the wall the panel is on and use two grounding rods outside?  8 ft between rods plus a few feet from panel to first rod.  Grounding cable not supposed to be spliced unless the splice cannot be undone, so a steel beam will not cut it.

Comment: How deeply are the supports footed into the floor?  This steel may be *required* to be part of the earthing system...

Comment: You can't use it as a conductor to connect to the water pipe, but "buildng steel" **is** generally supposed to be tied to the grounding system, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

##### TL;DR No (unless AHJ approves, which I doubt)

The *typical* rules that I have heard of are any of the following:

(a) Outside only:

- One ground rod, with testing
- Two grounds, without testing
- [Ufer ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ufer_ground)

(b) Water pipe + any of the above

(c) Water pipe + one ground rod, without testing

Historically, some places have allowed *only water pipe* without outside at all

This is very much jurisdiction dependent, which in turn can be a combination of history, politics, local practices (e.g., prevalence of plastic water service pipe) and even inspector preference.

However, what is pretty clear is that *if* a water pipe ground is either required or optional (e.g., "installer's choice: 2 rods or (water pipe + 1 rod)") then it must be a continuous wire from panel to the water pipe, and that connection to the water pipe should be as close to the building entrance as possible to avoid the problem of pipe repairs (whether a full PEX replacement or even just a short section - any break in the copper can ruin the grounding).

The idea of using a steel beam as a conductor has two problems:

- Steel is not as good a conductor as copper (though not bad, and good enough for conduit to be used as ground for circuits to the panel)
- Making sure the connection is never broken.

The last one is key. You would have two grounding wires. The one from the panel to the steel beam would be obvious. The one from the steel beam to the water pipe would *not* be obvious. The next owner might do some renovations, find the wire in the way, not understand it ("why would anyone put this wire here - it doesn't connect to the panel - must be some hack for some strange project") and get rid of it.